# What's the best way to drop a Laravel 4.2 table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-migrations

I've been creating tables using migrations per the documentation, and now I've rebuilt a section of my website and now I don't need one of my older tables.

I could:

A) Create a new migration file and tell it to drop the table in the "up" function, which doesn't make semantic sense, but does make sense from a procedural standpoint.

or

B) I can manually run a rollback on that specific migration, which does make sense semantically, but doesn't make sense procedurally and requires a manual action using CLI, meaning anyone using this software ever has extra steps unless I also remove the migration file, which now makes this not makes sense semantically, and if someone issued a reset there would be missing migrations.

Is there a better option that I'm missing?

Comment: If you're really worried about messing something up by removing this table, why not just leave it? Is there a reason you absolutely need it removed from your database?

Comment: I'm not worried at all about messing something up by removing it. I'm asking for the best practice for removing tables using Laravel. The documentation covers best practices for adding and updating tables, but not removing them.

Comment: Ah, I see. Like Joseph said, removing them in `up` is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping a table in `up` makes perfect semantic sense.

You should be dropping the table in `up`, and recreating the table in its current form in `down`.

*La perfection soit atteinte non quand il n'y a plus rien à ajouter, mais quand il n'y a plus rien à retrancher.*

Comment: Why is the last part of your answer in French?

Comment: @TimLewis Because it's a [quote from Antoine de Saint Exupéry](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Antoine_de_Saint_Exup%C3%A9ry)

Comment: @lukasgeiter Hmm. Fancy, if you understand french :P

Comment: @TimLewis Of if you know how to use the internet ;) But I agree, a translation in the answer would be nice...

Comment: "Perfection is attained not when there is no longer anything to add, but when there is no longer anything to take away".